# Can`t get QTreeView model of QSortFilterProxyModel() outside of the init function

Tags: pyqt5, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have an application which displays JSON-file to the QTreeView. For this I created my own `QJsonTreeModel(QAbstractItemModel)` class for QTreeView model

In my `MainWindow.py` I implemented it like this:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, json_text: dict) -> None:
        self.tree_view = QTreeView()
        self.model = QJsonTreeModel()

        self.tree_view.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.tree_view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.open_right_click_menu)

        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.load(self.json_text)

    def open_right_click_menu(self, position) -> None:
        index = self.tree_view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        parent = index.parent()

        if not index.isValid():
            return
        # workes fine
        print(self.model.data(self.tree_view.selectedIndexes()[2], Qt.EditRole))
```

It works perfect but recently I needed to add search QLineEdit() field to find the input element in the tree. And for this task I found soultion with `QSortFilterProxyModel()`. Which I implemented like this:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, json_text: dict) -> None:
        self.tree_view = QTreeView()
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        
        self.model = QJsonTreeModel()
        self.model.load(self.json_text)

        self.tree_view.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.tree_view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.open_right_click_menu)

        self.filter_proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.filter_proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.filter_proxy_model.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive) # Qt.CaseSensitive
        self.filter_proxy_model.setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(True)
        self.filter_proxy_model.setFilterKeyColumn(-1)

        self.tree_view.setModel(self.filter_proxy_model)

        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self.filter_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp)

    def open_right_click_menu(self, position) -> None:
        index = self.tree_view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        parent = index.parent()

        if not index.isValid():
            return
        # not working rn. Segmentation fault
        print(self.model.data(self.tree_view.selectedIndexes()[2], Qt.EditRole))
        # also not working
        print(self.filter_proxy_model.sourceModel().data(self.tree_view.selectedIndexes()[2], Qt.EditRole))
```

It works fine, the input text is searched in the tree and displayed normally, but the problem is in other place. I have implemented right click menu for my QTreeView:

```
self.tree_view.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.tree_view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.open_right_click_menu)
```

And in `open_right_click_menu` function I need to call `self.model.data(self.tree_view.selectedIndexes()[2], Qt.EditRole)` (index is correct,  there are three columns) function or some another function of `QJsonTreeModel()` class which worked perfectly before adding `QSortFilterProxyModel()`. But after implementing `QSortFilterProxyModel()` I have got Segmentation fault when I am trying to call some function of `QJsonTreeModel()` class. Also I tried `self.filter_proxy_model.sourceModel().data(self.tree_view.selectedIndexes()[2], Qt.EditRole)` but it also causes Segmentation fault. Where am I wrong and how do I call functions of `QJsonTreeModel()` class properly?

Comment: Rather than explaining the whole process too verbosely, provide a [mre] instead.

Comment: What do you don`t understand in my question and what function or class I need to write in full? If I write each class completely the question would be too long and hard to understand in my opinion.

Comment: In fact I didn't ask you to write *in full*, but for a MRE. Your question cannot be answered right now because you provided lots of details but not the correct ones. For instance, we have absolutely *no idea* of how you get `some_index`. So, if you want to be helped, please read the link above and follow its directions, or at least provide enough code and the correct details to *actually* understand the problem.

Comment: I tried to provide MRE

Comment: @Leonid Where is your `QJsonTreeMoel` class? How do you expect people to debug problems with a custom model, if you don't show any of its code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595456/qsortfilterproxymodel-qabstractitemmodel-modelindex-internalpointer-cause-cr) question before I asked mine, but the problem was that I did`t map QSortFilterProxyModel back. So the solution is this:

```
def open_right_click_menu(self, position) -> None:
    #  not working version
    print(self.model.data(self.tree_view.selectedIndexes()[2], Qt.EditRole))

    # working version
    print(self.model.data(
            self.filter_proxy_model.mapToSource(self.tree_view.selectedIndexes()[2]), Qt.EditRole))
```

Comment: Notes: 1. this will only work as long as the selected index list has *at least* 3 items, otherwise will crash due to `IndexError`, for example if you did *not* select any item and clicked on an empty area of the view; 2. since you need a context menu based on the item under the mouse, use [`indexAt()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#indexAt) (and eventually check `if index.isValid()`), not the selected indexes, which could include other indexes or use a different order; 3. QModelIndex already provides access to its data, so just use [`index.data()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#data).